# Componente switch de vuetify no es reactivo con el DOM en VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Tengo un error en funcionamiento con este componente de switch y metodo que esta asociado

Cuando doy click en el componente, me sale bien el modal, si respondo que no, deberia conservar el estado en el que se encontraba, pero por el contrario el componente se activa o desactiva.

Es decir, por defecto el componente se carga inactivo, le doy click y respondo que no, debería mantenerse inactivo, pero por el contrario se activa.

No se que hacer, ha he probado de todo, la logica me funciona bien, si respondo que no, la terminal me muestra el correspondiente log de no, pero el componente no esta actuando segun lo esperado!

````
<template v-slot:[`item.status_flag`]="{ item }">
                   <v-switch
                      inset
                      v-model="item.status_flag"
                      
                      @change="changeUsers(item)"
                      color="light-green accent-3"
                      >
                    </v-switch>
                </template>

changeUsers (item) {
        Swal.fire({
          title: '¿Deseas cambiar el estado de este beneficiario?',
          showDenyButton: true,
          confirmButtonText: 'SI',
          confirmButtonColor: '#80C300',
          denyButtonText: `NO`,
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.isConfirmed) {
            console.log(`si`);
            
          } else{
            console.log('No');
          }
            
        }) 
      }
```



He probado con click, change, mousedown, mouseup, pero obtengo el mismo resultado.
````